# How to force a re-render of React-Redux components upon React-Router-Dom NavLink click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have a React application built using [React-Router-Dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-dom) for navigation. The pages are very heavy on use of tables of data that can be opened in a CRUD form. Due to the amount of records we have in the tables, it's not uncommon for the user to apply sorting, filtering, and paging to the tables in order to find a desired record.

As a fairly standard web application, we have a navigation bar on the left-hand side of the page. This is built up of [NavLinks](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md).

The main body of the application is a component, `MainPanel`, that is almost entirely just a series of `Route` components within a `Switch`:

```
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/page1" component={ComponentOne} />
    <Route path="/page2" component={ComponentTwo} />
  </Switch>
```

I now have a request from above that when a user selects one of the NavLinks, it should act as a "reset" for everything in the main body of the page. In particular, this should act as a "reset" for all the settings of the table (sort, filter, page, etc.).

This *seems* like it should almost be trivial, as all I have to do is trigger a re-render of the main panel of the page holding the table. However, I can't find anything in the documentation for React-Router-Dom that holds the key to this.

Anybody got any idea what I'm missing? Is there no easy/right way to say, "When clicking this link, always re-render the MainPanel?

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep a value in state, e.g. called `panelKey`, that you use as `key` prop for the main panel. You then give `panelKey` a new value when the the link is clicked, and React will throw away the main panel and create an entirely new component.

**Example**

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  timer = null;
  state = { count: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.count}</div>;
  }
}

class MainPanel extends React.Component {
  state = { panelKey: 1 };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ panelKey: prevState.panelKey + 1 }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div key={this.state.panelKey}>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}> Reset Panel </button>
        <Timer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MainPanel />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer, as it works, it just needed a little bit of tweaking to work out some kinks.

Answer (score -1):

I see you have listed react-redux in the tags, why not dispatch a custom action to notify other components that filters should be reset?

```
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux';
import { resetFilter } from './filterActions.js';

const resetFilterMiddleware = ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
    // Listen for a location chnage
    if(action.type === LOCATION_CHANGE){
        dispatch(resetFilter()); // { type: 'RESET_FILTER' } or something along the lines
    }

    next(action);
}

export default resetFilterMiddleware;
```

Comment: I don't think this would ever work, as there is no location change; we're talking about selecting the same link, which should never fire that event.

Comment: it depends on the way you have implemented the navigation, if you are using `dispatch(push('/example'))` then it will work, regardless if the user is on the same page